# Uniform convergence of this particular limit functional

Tags: calculus, limits, uniform-convergence

Let $\{h_n(x)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a family of infinitely differentiable functions, defined on the entire real line, vanishing outside $[a,b]$. Let $F(x)$ be any function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ with the property that $F$ and all its derivatives are $O(|x|^{-N})$ as $|x|\to\infty$, for every $N$.

By hypothesis, the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{x=a}^b h_n(x)F(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

exists for any $F$ of the type specified above.

Is it true or false that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{x=a}^b h_n(x)F(x+\tau)\mathrm{d}x$ converge *uniformly* w.r.t. $\tau\in[\tau_1,\tau_2]\subset\mathbb{R}$?

I tried with Cauchy criterion, but without success...
If the answer is "no", with which hypothesis the answer could become "yes"?

Comment: Since the $h_n$'s are supported in $[a,b]$, the condition on $F$ is off topic. You could as well assume that for any smooth function $F$ on $[a,b]$ (where smooth at an endpoint $c$ means: the one-sided $n$-th derivative at $c$ exists for all $n$ and equals the one-sided limit of $F^{(n)}$ at $c$) $\lim\int_a^bh_nF$ exists.

Comment: @AnneBauval I guess it is not quite off-topic, just misplaced. Once we shift, we need some control on $F$ outside of the interval, no?

Comment: It is better to 1) focus on one question per post. Here: (proof or more probably) "counterexample?" And in another post: "additional hypothesis?" 2) add [some personal work](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Not really: if I understand the OP's (not so clear) quantifications correctly, the conjecture is: if for every smooth function $F$ on $[a,b]$, $\lim\int_a^bh_nF$ exists, then for every smooth function $G$ on $[a+\tau_1,b+\tau_2],$ the sequence $(\int_a^bh_n(x)G(x+\tau)dx)_n$ converges uniformly w.r.t. $\tau\in[\tau_1,\tau_2].$

Comment: @AnneBauval I agree with your interpretation, but you now also added some condition on (now) $G$. Most certainly I am not claiming that you need as much decay as stated in the OP, but you need some control on the function outside of $[a,b]$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven No control is needed outside the domain $[a+\tau_1,b+\tau_2]$ where $G$ is used (in particular no "decay" control), because (like $F$) [$G$ can always be extended to a smooth function on $\Bbb R$](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem), and then multiplied by some smooth compactly supported function equal to $1$ on $[a+\tau_1,b+\tau_2].$

Comment: @AnneBauval I am fully aware of all of that. All I am saying is that knowing $F$ on $[a,b]$ is not sufficient (which is obviously clear to you).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven All I was saying (in the comment beginning with " Not really") is that knowing the $F$'s on $[a,b]$ in the hypothesis, and the *other* $F$'s (which I therefore renamed $G$) on $[a+\tau_1,b+\tau_2]$ in the conclusion, is sufficient. This is why I initially claimed that for both, the decay condition is off topic. You certainly agree but this may be useful for the OP.

Comment: @AnneBauval Indeed, it seems we agree on everything. I just kept misunderstamding you :(

Comment: The conclusion does not hold without additional assumptions. An example can be constructed so that $\int\limits_a^bh_n(x)F(x)\,dx=0$ for all $n$ and $\int\limits_a^bh_n(x)F(x+\tau)\,dx$ has no limit on any given interval $(\tau_1,\tau_2).$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Mind the universal quantifier on $F$, in the hypothesis as well as, indepedently, in the conclusion.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks. I have overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments of your post, the hypothesis on $F$ toward infinity is useless. We can choose $F$ to be any smooth function defined over $\mathbb{R}$. But since only the values of $F$ on a neighborhood of $[a,b]$ are important, we can assume that $F$ has a compact support if needed.

I can answer positively to your question if we add the hypothesis that the sequence $\|h_n\|_{L^1} = \int_a^b |h_n(x)| dx$ is bounded. In this case, by uniform continuity of $F$ (it can be assumed compactly supported thus Heine theorem holds), $\tau \mapsto (x \mapsto F(x + \tau))$ is continuous for the $L^\infty$ norm (just play with $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ and the definition of uniform continuity). If we set for all $n$ and $\tau$,
$$
I_n(\tau) = \int_a^b h_n(x)F(x + \tau) dx
$$
and $I(\tau) = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} I_n(\tau)$ (which exists by hypothesis), we have for all $n,\tau,t$,
$$
|I_n(t) - I_n(\tau)| \leqslant \left|\int_a^b h_n(x)(F(x + \tau) - F(x + t))\right| \leqslant \|h_n\|_{L^1}\|x \mapsto F(x + \tau) - F(x + t)\|_{L^\infty}.
$$
By continuity of $\tau \mapsto (x \mapsto F(x + \tau))$ and boundedness of $(\|h_n\|_{L^1})$, we deduce that the $I_n$ are uniformly continuous, thus its limit $I$ is continuous, which is the wanted result.

In the general case, the question is harder. For example, if you take $h_n(x) = n^k\cos(2\pi(b - a)nx)$ on some $[a + \varepsilon,b - \varepsilon]$ that you extend into a smooth function supported in $[a,b]$, you can show that your hypothesis holds for any smooth $F$ and any $k \geqslant 0$ (look at the convergence speed of Fourrier coefficients) but if $k > 0$, the hypothesis I added is not verified.

Try to see if this particular case is a counter-example, it may help you to find a counter-example or a proof in the general case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, the hypotesis on the boundedness of the norm of $h_n$ cannot be assumed. Anyway, I want to thank you for your interest.